# Natural Sort with point and alphanumeric

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called tbl_sort with these rows:

```
+---------------+
| sort_alphanum |
+---------------+
| 1             |
| 1.1           |
| 1.10          |
| 1.2           |
| 10            |
| 2a            |
| 3b            |
+---------------+
```

I want to sort these rows to what is called 'natural sort' and look like this:

```
+---------------+
| sort_alphanum |
+---------------+
| 1             |
| 1.1           |
| 1.2           |
| 1.10          |
| 2a            |
| 3b            |
| 10            |
+---------------+
```

I've tried this syntax:

```
SELECT
tbl_sort.sort_alphanum
FROM
tbl_sort
ORDER BY CAST(sort_alphanum AS UNSIGNED), sort_alphanum
```

But the above resulted as below:

```
+---------------+
| sort_alphanum |
+---------------+
| 1             |
| 1.1           |
| 1.10          |
| 1.2           |
| 2a            |
| 3b            |
| 10            |
+---------------+
```

As you can see the 1.10 row is suppose to be placed after 1.2. How do I achieve the result like the first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
SELECT
tbl_sort.sort_alphanum
FROM
tbl_sort ORDER BY 
CONVERT(sort_alphanum,DECIMAL(10,0)) asc,
CAST(SUBSTR(sort_alphanum FROM 3) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following, it only gives you your expected result for your sample data, not sure if it works for real data or not, anyway try it.

```
SELECT
    sort_alphanum
FROM tbl_sort
-- WHERE sort_alphanum IN ('1.1', '1.10', '1.2')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LOCATE('.', sort_alphanum) THEN LEFT(sort_alphanum, LOCATE('.', sort_alphanum) - 1) ELSE sort_alphanum END + 0,
CASE WHEN LOCATE('.', sort_alphanum) THEN REPLACE(sort_alphanum, '.', '') END + 0
```

And [SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fd8dc/3)